# How to unregister SMS broadcast receiver in android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

In android widget application, i used a broadcast receiver to intercept sms for certain purpose.  It is working fine... but a problem arises when i removes the widget from home screen.  SMS is not coming to inbox.  My question is how to unregister SMS receiver ?

please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you are registering you receiver in manifest file. Remove it from manifest and try to register it using `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver myreceiver, IntentFilter filter)` in your `onCreate()` or `onResume()`, and when you want to unregister it, use `unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver myreceiver)` in your `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`. Hope it will work...

Comment: the unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver myreceiver) is undefined for a widget.

Comment: use contex.unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver myreceiver)